# Changing Azure restriction behaviour

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service, firewall, http-status-code-403, restriction

I have a website with restricted access. Only a number of IPs are allowed to access the site. I have configured the Access Restrictions for the web site so that only specified clients can access the app.

The problem is that all denied clients received a 403 http response status code with the following message:

Error 403 - This web app is stopped.

How could I change this behaviour, so that denid clients receive no response at all?

Answer (score 1):

How about using "Dynamic IP Restrictions feature". 
https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/blog/confirming-dynamic-ip-address-restrictions-in-windows-azure-web-sites/

Example:

```
<system.webServer>
   <security>
      <ipSecurity allowUnlisted="false" denyAction="NotFound">
         <add allowed="true" ipAddress="1.2.3.4"subnetMask="255.255.0.0"/>
      </ipSecurity>
   </security>
</system.webServer>
```

The allowable values for denyAction are:

- AbortRequest  (returns an HTTP status code of 0)
- Unauthorized (returns an HTTP status code of 401)
- Forbidden (returns an HTTP status code of 403).
  Note this is the default setting.
- NotFound (returns an HTTP status code of 404)

Comment: well this could be one way of doing it. I was more interested in changing the behavior on the azure side.